# MFC Ribbon imports as XML instead of opening designer after saving

Tags: c++, xml, visual-studio, mfc

I made a resource file from scratch - I renamed an empty .txt file to .rc and then opened it in Visual Studio. Then I added a ribbon, a dialog, etc. to it. Then I saved and quit. When I reopened the file again, Visual Studio complained:

```
error RC2144 : PRIMARY LANGUAGE ID not a number
```

... which was fixed by adding `#include <windows.h>` in the resource.rc file.

But when I opened the file again, I got this:
[MFC Ribbon Error RT_RIBBON_XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhWc9.png)

Visual Studio seems to import the ribbon as an "RT_RIBBON_XML" type, not as a "Ribbon" like usual. As you can see, it says that there's an "external file" - and yes, the ribbon XML itself is in a seperate file in the same directory. But I can't open the ribbon in the designer anymore, it just shows the XML instead of the Ribbon designer. How can I tell Visual Studio that this XML is indeed a ribbon?

I have tried importing the ribbon via "Add resource > Import", but I can't import it as a "Ribbon" type, but Visual Studio says it's not allowed to open an external type as a built-in type.

I've tried making a new ribbon, then opening the data and copy-pasting from my old ribbon into the new ribbon. The ribbon gets saved correctly, but Visual Studio doesn't open the file anymore, meaning: When I open the file in a text editor, I can see all my attributes, but when opening it in the designer, it's simply an empty ribbon. How can I load my original ribbon?

Comment: Is your ribbon available for the primary language set in the resource script?

Comment: Yes, if I look into the .rc file: `IDR_RIBBON1 RT_RIBBON_XML "resources\\ribbon1.mfcribbon-ms"`

Comment: I have noticed that the error occured as soon as I added `#include <windows.h>` in the resource script